# Is the right-hand term of the dynamic system equivalent to the original system after being multiplied by a constant?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations

Given two dynamical systems where $f$ is lipschitz for $x$ : $\begin{cases}  x'(t)=af(x,t),\\ x(0)=x_0,\end{cases} t\in[0,\tau]$ and $\begin{cases} z'(t)=f(z,t),\\ z(0)=x_0,\end{cases} t\in[0,\tau']$, and their flowmaps $\phi_{af}^\tau(x),\phi_f^{\tau'}(x)$, if $\tau'=a\tau$, can we say   $\phi_{af}^\tau(x_0)=\phi_f^{\tau'}(x_0)$ for any $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$?

How about in a higher dimension?
$\begin{cases} x'(t)=Af(x,t),\\ x(0)=x_0,\end{cases} t\in[0,\tau]$ and $\begin{cases}z'(t)=f(z,t),\\ z(0)=x_0,\end{cases} t\in[0,\tau']$ where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is diagonal matrix? what is the relationship between $\phi_{Af}^\tau(x_0)$ and $\phi_f^{\tau'}(x_0)$

Comment: Is $\dot z$ the same as $z$?

Comment: $z$ is just a notation to make two odes seem independent to each other

Comment: But what is that $z$ you have written with a dot on top of it?

Comment: I can't see any dots on top of $z$ from my perspective, I have deleted all \dot in my original code and changed it into $z'(t)$

Comment: There used to be two dotted $z$s, now there is still one dotted $z$.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, there maybe something wrong with my website and I can not see any dots in this page, now I check the code and have deleted all dots

Comment: I have accepted your answer, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course not. Take about any smooth $f(x,t)$ depending on $t$.

E.g., take $f(x,t)=x+t$, so that for $a\ne0$
$$\phi^t_{af}(x_0)=\frac{a x_0 e^{a t}-a t+e^{a t}-1}{a},$$
so that
$$\phi^t_{af}(x_0)-\phi^{at}_f(x_0)=\frac{(a-1) \left(1+a t-e^{a t}\right)}{a}\ne0$$
if $a\notin\{0,1\}$ and $t\ne0$.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the second question:
there is hardly any useful relationship between the flows. Such systems may not be even topologically equivalent even for the case of linear autonomous systems. For example:
$$\tag{1}
\left\{
\begin{array}{lrr}
\dot x_1=&-x_1&-\frac12 x_2\\
\dot x_2=&3x_1&+x_2.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Since the eigenvalues of the matrix of the system are $\pm \frac1{\sqrt2}i$, the phase portrait of (1) is a center. If we multiply the right side of the system by the matrix
$A=\left(\begin{array}{rr}
1&0\\ 0&2
\end{array}\right)
$, we obtain
$$\tag{2}
\left\{
\begin{array}{lrr}
\dot x_1=&-x_1&-\frac12 x_2\\
\dot x_2=&6x_1&+2x_2.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
The eigenvalues of the matrix of the system are now $\frac12\pm \frac{\sqrt3}{2}i$, so the phase portrait of (2) is an unstable focus.